# Making non-dynamic material table dynamic

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have legacy code, and I want to understand how angular works with for loops. I'm trying to shorten this code, but its hard to follow pattern:

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[0].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.gid}} <span class="resize-handle" (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gid}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[1].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.category}}
        <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="categoryMenu" aria-label="Icon-button with a menu">
          <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span class="resize-handle" (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <a>{{row.category}}</a>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[2].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.serialKey}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 2, row.category)">
        <a
          *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 2">{{row.serialKey}}</a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 2)"
          value={{row.serialKey}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[3].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.producer}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 3, row.category)">
        <a
          *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 3">{{row.producer}}</a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 3)"
          value={{row.producer}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)" list="itemProducer">
        <datalist id="itemProducer">
          <option *ngFor="let producer of globalVariables.dataLists.producer" value={{producer}}> {{producer}}
          </option>
        </datalist>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[4].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div class="column-content">
          {{globalVariables.texts.labels.model}} <span class="resize-handle"
            (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 4, row.category)">
        <div class="column-content">
          <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 4">{{row.model}}
          </a>
          <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 4)"
            value={{row.model}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)" list="itemModels">
          <datalist id="itemModels">
            <option *ngFor="let model of globalVariables.dataLists.model" value={{model}}> {{model}} </option>
          </datalist>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[5].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.type}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 5, row.category)">
        <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 5">{{row.type}}
        </a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 5)"
          value={{row.type}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)" list="itemTypes">
        <datalist id="itemTypes">
          <option *ngFor="let type of globalVariables.dataLists.types" value={{type}}> {{type}} </option>
        </datalist>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[6].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.location}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 6, row.category)">
        <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 6">{{row.location}}
        </a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 6)"
          value={{row.location}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)" list="itemLocation">
        <datalist id="itemLocation">
          <option *ngFor="let local of globalVariables.dataLists.location" value={{local}}> {{local}} </option>
        </datalist>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[7].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.count}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 7, row.category)">
        <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 7">{{row.count}}
        </a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 7)"
          value={{row.count}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[8].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.notes}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="notes" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 8, row.category)">
        <textarea disabled class="textarea" matInput
          *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 8">{{row.notes}} </textarea>
        <textarea matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 8)"
          value={{row.notes}} class="textarea" onfocus="this.select()" #inSK
          (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)"></textarea>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[9].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.purchased}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 9, row.category)">
        <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 9">{{row.purchased
          |
          date}} </a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 9)"
          value={{row.purchased}} onfocus="this.select()" type="date" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[10].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.leased}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 10, row.category)">
        <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 10">
          <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="leased" *ngIf="row.leased">check_circle_outline</mat-icon>
        </a>
        <mat-checkbox *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 10)"
          [ngModel]="row.leased" (change)="valueChange(!row.leased)"></mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[11].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.leasedUntil}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 11, row.category)">
        <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 11">
          <a *ngIf="row.leased">{{row.leasingUntil | date}}</a>
        </a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 11)"
          value={{row.leasingUntil}} onfocus="this.select()" type="date" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[12].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.serviceUntil}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 12, row.category)">
        <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 12">{{row.serviceUntil
          | date}} </a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 12)"
          value={{row.serviceUntil}} onfocus="this.select()" type="date" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)">
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef={{columns[13].field}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="resizable-header">
        {{globalVariables.texts.labels.pcRel}} <span class="resize-handle"
          (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (dblclick)="double(row.gid, 13, row.category)">
        <a *ngIf="globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 13">{{row.pc}}
        </a>
        <input matInput *ngIf="!(globalVariables.editCell.gid !== row.gid || globalVariables.editCell.column !== 13)"
          value={{row.pc}} onfocus="this.select()" #inSK (change)="valueChange(inSK.value)" list="itemPCRel">
        <datalist id="itemPCRel">
          <option *ngFor="let rel of globalVariables.dataLists.pcRel" value={{rel}}> {{rel}} </option>
        </datalist>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky:true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event, row)"></tr>
    <tr *matNoDataRow>
      <td colspan="14">{{globalVariables.texts.phrases.noMatchingData}} "{{input.value}}" in
        "{{globalVariables.selectedCategory}}"</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I tried to do it this way, but I have feeling it will be pretty hard. If possible that someone writes it, so I can understand how ngfor, ngswitch etc works. thanks

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index" matColumnDef="{{column.field}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >

        {{globalVariables?.texts?.labels[column.field]}} <ng-container *ngIf="column.field==='category'"> <button
            mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="categoryMenu" aria-label="Icon-button with a menu">
            <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
          </button></ng-container>
        <span class="resize-handle" (mousedown)="onResizeColumn($event, i)"></span>
      </th>

      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <div class="column-content">{{ row[column.field] }}


        </div>
      </td>

    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    <tr *matNoDataRow>
      <td colspan="14">{{globalVariables.texts.phrases.noMatchingData}} "{{input.value}}" in
        "{{globalVariables.selectedCategory}}"</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks quite extensive as there is a separate  code block for each column of the table. To simplify this code, you can try using *ngFor loop to generate the columns dynamically. Unfortunately, due to the complexity and variety of columns, this approach can be quite complex to implement.

My suggestion is to separate some of the code into sub-components, which will allow for better organization and increase readability. While this won't directly shorten your code, it will make it easier to manage and understand.

In other words, shortening this code can be difficult due to the variety of columns, but you can streamline its organization by breaking it down into smaller components.

Create an interface e.g. "ColumnConfig" representing the column configuration:

```
export interface ColumnConfig {
  component: Type<any>;
  inputData: any;
}
```

In the main component of the table (e.g. table.component.ts) define an array with column configuration:

```
export class TableComponent {
  columns: ColumnConfig[] = [
    {
      component: ColumnAComponent,
      inputData: { /* data for ColumnAComponent */ },
    },
    {
      component: ColumnBComponent,
      inputData: { /* data for ColumnBComponent */ },
    },
    // ...
  ];
}
```

In the main table component HTML file (table.component.html), use the *ngFor directive with ngComponentOutlet to dynamically generate the column components. Example with some native HTML table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <!-- Some table label -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
      <td *ngFor="let column of columns; let idx = index">
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="column.component; injector: createInjector(column.inputData, idx, row)">
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the table component, add a function, e.g. "createInjector" that generates an Injector with the transferred data:

```
export class TableComponent {
  // ...

  createInjector(inputData: any, columnIndex: number, rowData: any): Injector {
    return Injector.create({
      providers: [
        { provide: 'inputData', useValue: inputData },
        { provide: 'columnIndex', useValue: columnIndex },
        { provide: 'rowData', useValue: rowData },
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

Now in column components (e.g. column-a.component.ts, column-b.component.ts, etc.) you can access the passed data with @Inject:

```
export class ColumnAComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject('inputData') public inputData: any,
    @Inject('columnIndex') public columnIndex: number,
    @Inject('rowData') public rowData: any
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This way you can dynamically generate different column components.

In the column components (column-a.component.html and column-b.component.html, etc.) create the appropriate HTML templates using the given data:

**column-a.component.html:**

```
<div>
  <!-- An example of using the passed data in the ColumnAComponent template -->
  {{ rowData[columnIndex] }}
</div>
```

**column-b.component.html:**

```
<div>
  <!-- An example of using the passed data in the ColumnBComponent template -->
  {{ rowData[columnIndex] }}
</div>
```

This way you can dynamically generate different column components and pass data and column indexes to them in a loop. Note that this example assumes that the data for the row is stored as an array of values. So you use rowData[columnIndex] in your column component templates to get the value of the corresponding column for a given row.

With this structure, you can dynamically create column components with different inputs and differentiate them by passing values.